# How do I upgrade the Android LG G2 D802 to Kitkat OS?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, adb, 4.2-jelly-bean

I bought LG G2 phone just a few days and I wanted to upgrade it to possibly Android 4.4 Kitkat from Android 4.2 Jellybean (I think which is the software update is trying to do as well as shown in screenshot). What I do is go the 'Update Center > Software Update > Check now for update which shows up the following screenshot:

[image]

After a few megabytes of downloading, the download manager reports "Cannot connect to server" and there's no way to resume it. I am sure there's nothing wrong with my Wi-fi either.

Is there an alternative way to manually grab this so called update via PC?

### Update 1:

I downloaded the LG PC Suite and connected the phone via USB to check to see if it can upgrade but apparently it looks like it is trying to apply the Lollipop upgrade and I have no option to choose:

[image]

### Update 2

I have tried to install ADB from Android SDK by following several tutorials on the Internet and got it working via. USB Debugging. Then I followed the steps [here](http://www.droid-life.com/2014/06/05/download-nexus-ota-url-file/) and used the command `adb logcat >log.txt` on Windows OS from CMD.

As I initialize the update from Apps > Update Center > Software Update, it fills the text file with log it collects but I cannot find any `http://` or `https://` link in the file after I click 'Download Update' in the Update Center on LG G2 D802 device.

I still got no such luck.

### Update 3

From the @[eldarerathi](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/981/eldarerathis) comment:

> The article's instructions are for Nexus devices. Most probably, LG's
>   update code doesn't do the same logging. In particular, Nexus devices
>   don't have an 'Update Center' app - OTA update checks are done in the
>   Settings app. As to how to do it on your device: that may be difficult
>   to know, since LG likely doesn't release the source for their 'Update
>   Center' app. Some kind of network monitoring may be worth exploring.

on my other related question it appears that adb won't be helpful in this case.

Comment: I am currently trying to use the method in Update 1. I clicked the upgrade button and immeditately disconnected the phone from USB. Now, it is trying to download a file called "D80220D_00.kdz" which will apparently going to be about the size of 1.6 GB judging from the progress and google research. I am not sure what I'd do with it and if it is only a Kitkat or lollipop upgrade or both.

Comment: As soon as the downloaded completed for 1.6 GB file the PC Suite immediately deleted off the file due to the reason that phone wasn't connected. This seems to be so absurd.